# Windows USB keyboard and mouse won't work, PS/2 keyboard does

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, keyboard, mouse

Everything was functioning properly. I turned my computer off and came back to it a couple of days later to find that the keyboard and mouse are not working in Windows.

I am running Windows 7, 64 bit. To see if this was a Windows problem, I checked to see if the keyboard and mouse still work in the BIOS, and they do perfectly:
The keyboard is one of those fancy (lights, macros and all that stuff) keyboards. When I turn on the computer and enter BIOS the keyboard lights up like it should with all the keys lit. The mouse which also has a special green light on top of it also does.

But when Windows boots up, during the windows loading logo screen the keyboard and mouse lights suddenly all turn off, then the login screen appears and suddenly only some of the keyboard buttons light up faintly, as if the keyboard is getting power but not enough.

I am currently using a PS/2 keyboard to type this, and it works perfectly.

Connecting and disconnecting the mouse or the keyboard to a different USB port (I tried USB2 and USB3) makes Windows try to install (or search?) for drivers, then if fails and gives me this window:

[image: "Driver Software Installation. Device driver software was not successfully installed. Please consult with your device manufacturer for assitance getting this device installed. USB Composite Device Failed."]

If you can't see the image for some reason or for the search engines, it's a window that says:
"Driver Software Installation. Device driver software was not successfully installed. Please consult with your device manufacturer for assistance getting this device installed. USB Composite Device Failed."

Windows will also sometimes do this right after I log in.

I tried Googling for hours and saw that people also have the same general problem (works in BIOS, not in Windows) and I tried all the solutions I could find (removing all power for the PC, resetting BIOS settings, Windows Update stuff, etc.).

Any help on how to solve this problem will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to remove all of your usb hubs from device manager, so that they are installed again?

Also you can try remove all non existing keyboard/mouse devices with following commands.
Open command prompt as administrator, type SET devmgr_show_nonpresent_devices=1
and after it open device manager with typing, devmgmt.msc.

After it view -> show hidden devices. Now you should see all devices that have been installed on your computer at some point. You can safely remove devices that are little bit faded out (under keyboard and mice)

Comment: First of all thanks. Doing what you told me lead me to understand that Windows won't load the drivers for my mouse and keyboard because they are not digitally signed.

I tried booting Windows with F8 and selected the option to ignore digital signatures for drivers and the keyboard and mouse work in this mode.

So what should I do to fix the signatures for the driver files, because as I understand this mode is unsecure?

Comment: @omer Thank you very much! I had this exact same problem and ignoring driver signatures worked for me. You saved me potentially days of trying to fix my computer. Please post it as an answer so other people know about this as well.

Answer (score -1):

I (on 3-5-2017) run a Windows  64 bit and in recent months had my mouse disconnecting and connecting time and time  again, even just when starting up the computer. I knew it never could be the mouse as I use this mouse and others on other computers without hassle. today I decided  to plug in the mouse in a USB fitting on the other side of the laptop and immediately all disconnections/connections was at an end. I commenced to play a computer game again and without any disconnection since I moved the mouse to a different USB fitting.

As such, the solution appears to be to move the mouse USB to a  different socket.

It might be that the USB socket has a loose connection and this is what really caused the disconnect./connect every few seconds, as the laptop was on a table and not being moved and neither so was I touching the laptop and it still was previously every couple of seconds disconnecting and connection.